# Se puede convertir un aplicacion jquery mobile en un apk Android o IOS

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, aplicación-web

Estoy haciendo una app moblie utilizando jquery mobile pero tengo la intencion de convertirla en una apk nativa. Cual es la manera mas efectiva de hacerlo?

Comment: Una solución es usar Intel XDK, podría decirse que es un front-end de Apache Cordoba.

Answer (score 3):

Existen varias herramientas para realizar esto pero la mejor opción sería desarrollarla con **[Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)**.

https://auth0.com/blog/converting-your-web-app-to-mobile/

Otras opciones:

- https://median.co/ (previamente *gonative.io*)
- https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk
- http://phonegap.com/

Si lo que deseas es convertir tu web site en un .apk u .ipa existen algunos servicios que lo pueden realizar (no lo recomendaría, lo mejor es realizarla con un framework destinado para esto)...

http://www.appypie.com/convert-website-to-mobile-apps